# Fail to serialize C# object to Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I was trying to serialize an object to Json and return it to my view, but it fail in these two ways:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(vm);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
```

Here is my full code of this controller method:

```
public ActionResult Listagem(int id = 1)
{
    int pagina = id;

    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    UsuariosViewModel vm = new UsuariosViewModel
    {
        Usuarios = manager.Users.Where(m => m.Ativo)
        .OrderBy(m => m.Nome)
        .Skip((pagina - 1) * UsuariosPorPagina)
        .Take(UsuariosPorPagina),

        Paginacao = new Paginacao
        {
            PaginaAtual = pagina,
            ItensPorPagina = UsuariosPorPagina
        }
    };

    vm.Paginacao.ItensTotal = manager.Users.Where(m => m.Ativo).Count();
    //var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(vm);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);

    return Content(json);
}
```

And here is the error that I'm getting:

[image: Error]

I can't figure out where is the DataReader that I left opened.

Comment: Could you translate the inner exception to English?

Comment: Try by adding `.ToList()` to the end of your queries (`manager.Users.....`)

Comment: Translated from Portuguese: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Comment: I was translating, tks @DavidG!

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli Você é bem-vindo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework does not execute the extension methods directly but keeps the LINQ statements in memory until they are used. Through this behavior, your `Usuarios` object is a non-evaluated LINQ query and will be exectued once the property is accessed (this can easily seen when debugging the code). To evaluate the query directly, you can add `.ToList()` to the statement, e.g.

```
UsuariosViewModel vm = new UsuariosViewModel
    {
        Usuarios = manager.Users.Where(m => m.Ativo)
        .OrderBy(m => m.Nome)
        .Skip((pagina - 1) * UsuariosPorPagina)
        .Take(UsuariosPorPagina)
        .ToList(),

        Paginacao = new Paginacao
        {
            PaginaAtual = pagina,
            ItensPorPagina = UsuariosPorPagina
        }
    };
```